# OIDC based single sign-on

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, openid-connect

How does OIDC based SSO works? Is it recommended to store OIDC token on browser? Is it safe enough? If OIDC token is stored at server side, how to pass this when browser redirection happens in order to access other SPA application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article "**[Identity Federation by OpenID Connect](https://medium.com/@darutk/identity-federation-by-openid-connect-9f8f0a189826)**" explains how OIDC-based SSO works.

[image]